# The annotation @EventListener is disallowed for this location

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have written this class along with EventListener annotation and a triggerMail method--

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringEmailClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringEmailClientApplication.class, args);
                    
        //EventListner will be triggered when application is ready
        @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
        public void triggerMail() {
            
        }
    }

}
```

But,in eclipse ide it is giving error The annotation @EventListener is disallowed for this location and Illegal modifier for parameter triggerMail; only final is permitted .

How to fix this issue ?Please help .

Comment: Can you move triggerMail method out of main method and put it into class?

Comment: Yes, the errors are gone now .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringEmailClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringEmailClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    //EventListner will be triggered when application is ready
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void triggerMail() {
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, tho this might be an exception because it boils down to moving a curly bracket to have the triggerMail() outside the main function.